# period range selection control in ASP.NET MVC3

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, slider

I want to implement similar slider than i mention in attached image.

I want the slider that able to select date like 14/09  to 24/05. So basically,
I want allow user to select this period in one shot rather than creating multiple period with 
14/09 to 31/dec and 01/01 to 24/05.

[image: The one we did in asp.net webform]

As you can see, there are two sliders, the first one is "from", and the second one is "to", the user can move each slider to adjust the period selection.

Is there any third-party controls (jquery based preferred) so achieve similar effect?

Comment: check this - http://ghusse.github.com/jQRangeSlider/

Comment: I generally use one illustrated in jquery UI demo! I also like the one pointed by @zero7. But if you are looking for specific UI, will advise to roll your own implementation.

Comment: jQRangeSlider looks pretty good, and VinayC is right, I need to customize it. zero7, please post your answer so that I can close the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Jquery Slider with range option false. so that you can move your from and to pointers freely across the range line and to show overlay period create another two sliders and hide and show them dynamically based on from and to selection.

```
 function sliderOperatingControl(controlId, rangeVal, minVal, maxVal, valuesVal, slideLogic) {
        $(controlId).slider({
            range: rangeVal,
            min: minVal,
            max: maxVal,
            values: valuesVal,
            slide: slideLogic
        });
    }
 $(function () {
 sliderOperatingControl("#sliderFrom", false, 1, 365, [1, 365], function (event, ui) {
             var strDate = returnDate(ui.values[0]) + " To " + returnDate(ui.values[1]);
             $("#periodFromToLabel").html("Range: " + strDate);
             $("#SliderDisplay").slider("values", 0, ui.values[0]);
             $("#SliderDisplay").slider("values", 1, ui.values[1]);
             if (ui.values[0] > ui.values[1]) {
                 $("#SliderDisplay").slider("values", 0, ui.values[0]);
                 $("#SliderDisplay").slider("values", 1, 365);
                 $("#SliderDisplay2").slider("values", 0, 0);
                 $("#SliderDisplay2").slider("values", 1, ui.values[1]);
                 $("#SliderDisplay2").show();
             }
             else {
                 $("#SliderDisplay").slider("values", 0, ui.values[0]);
                 $("#SliderDisplay").slider("values", 1, ui.values[1]);
                 $("#SliderDisplay2").hide();
             }

         });
});
```

So SliderDisplay and SliderDisplay2 can be dynamically made hidden or visible based on from and to range selection.